# ArcMap 10.0 won't load

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcgis-desktop, arcmap, windows-7

ArcMap 10.0 on a Windows 7, 32-bit computer stopped loading two days ago.  It worked perfectly before then.  ArcCatalog, etc., all continue to open fine.  Task Manager indicates ArcMap is trying to load, but very, very slowly.  I deleted Normal.mxt, and tried to restart ArcMap, but it has not yet successfully opened up and has not re-created Normal.mxt.

Comment: Do you have any third party extensions or add ons? Have you recently added or updated any third party extensions/add ons?

Comment: Install service pack 5. http://support.esri.com/en/downloads/patches-servicepacks/view/productid/66/metaid/1879

Answer (score 1):

Check out shuoqiwang's advice here: http://forums.arcgis.com/threads/85386-ArcMap-10.1-crashes-upon-opening

The post is for 10.1, but I'm thinking it's the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can still create an arcmap startup log as per [link](http://support.esri.com/em/knowledgebase/techarticles/detail/32828).  That might tell you something.